# Infinite loop with redirection, but runs properly with normal input

Tags: linux, c

My code works perfectly when input is directly in the terminal, but creates an infinite loop when used with input redirection (same content).

```
int main()
{
    int c,d;
    int x=1;
    while(x)
    {
        c=getchar();
        if((c>='A')&&(c<='J'))
        {
            d=getchar();
            if(d=='\n'||d==EOF)
            {
               if(c=='A')
                    x=0;
            }   

        }
        if(x)
        {
            printf("Invalid Input\n");//this keeps repeatingn  
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you do not show how `x` is set, it will hard to say why it is wrong.

Comment: @StephenRauch edited :)

Comment: I would suspect the line endings are your problem. try: `if(d=='\n'||d=='\r'||d==EOF)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really your program loops in *terminal* and with `pipe` input,the difference is that in *terminal* `getchar` blocks waiting for input but at `pipe` you get `EOF`.

You should check for `EOF` after each `getchar` invocation, so to solve your loop issue you could do,

```
int main()
{
    int c,d;
    int x=1;
    while(x)
    {
        c=getchar();

        /* EOF check */
        if (c == EOF)
            break;

        if((c>='A')&&(c<='J'))
        {
            d=getchar();
            if(d=='\n'||d==EOF)
            {
               if(c=='A')
                    x=0;
            }   

        }
        if(x)
        {
            printf("Invalid Input\n");//this keeps repeatingn  
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see the difference now! Thank you for the help.